# All post ids are the same after this query but rewind_posts() does not seem to work here?

Tags: theme-development, loop

I'm executing a query inside of header.php which is apparently resetting the $post object so that all pages are getting the $post->ID of the last element in this loop.

```
$mypostsheader = get_posts(array('cat' => "$cat,-$catHidden",'numberposts' => $cb2_current_count));
$current_page = get_post( $current_page );?>
<div class="menu top">
    <ul><?php foreach($mypostsheader as $idx=>$post){
        if ( $post->ID == $current_page->ID )//do something; }
```

I've tried adding a rewind_posts() at the end of this function and also at the end of header.php but my echo $post->ID inside of page.php still returns the id of the last element in the query.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're already saving the current page in __$current_page__. Why not just set `$post = $current_page; setup_postdata( $post );` after your loop? Or is there more to your question?

Comment: @goldenapples: good suggestion. I missed that. I actually got it to work using wp_reset_query() just before closing the function. I was previously trying to use rewind_posts() with no luck.

Comment: @goldenapples: Your suggestion works. Please post it as an answer and I will upvote it and select it. Actually, I don't even have to call setup_postdata($post). I'm just resetting the post with $post = $current_page as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that one solution for this was to place a call to wp_reset_query() just before the close of the function call. I was trying to use rewind_posts() but it would not work. wp_reset_query() did the trick.

After doing that, thanks to @goldenapples excellent observation that I was already setting a pointer to the current $post object with my $current_page variable (duh!), I found that I could dump the wp_reset_query() call and instead just add this line in its place...

```
$post = $current_page;
```

The root cause is that I was resetting the $post object in the for loop (as $idx=>$post) and the query had to be reset so that the value of $post was a true reflection of the current $post object for the page in function calls below header.php